# MySQL - MySqlDump uses \n instead of null

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump, mysql-5.1

Using Windows with MySQL 5.1.

I am running a script that uses mysqldump to backup a database.

The mysqldump syntax used is:

```
mysqldump --user=root --port=3306 --password=topsecret some_database --tab=C:\ARCHIVE\some_database --triggers --routines --fields-enclosed-by=\"" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by=\r\n
```

This creates a text file and when I open it all NULL fields show as \n

Is there a setting for mysqldump that would export NULL fields as NULL?

Answer (score 1):

There are no options for handling the output of NULLs.

You may want to experiment with `--hex-blob`. This will dump BINARY, VARBINARY, BLOB fields in hexadecimal format. This should make the data portable. You can see what this option produces for NULL values.

```
mysqldump --user=root --port=3306 --password=topsecret --hex-blob some_database --tab=C:\ARCHIVE\some_database --triggers --routines --fields-enclosed-by=\"" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by=\r\n
```

Give it a Try and let us all know if this helps.

### **UPDATE 2012-01-13 18:26 EDT**

This may sound very gross but you can pipe the output of mysqldump into sed as follows:

```
mysqldump --user=root --port=3306 --password=topsecret --hex-blob some_database --tab=C:\ARCHIVE\some_database --triggers --routines --fields-enclosed-by=\"" --fields-terminated-by=, --lines-terminated-by=\r\n | sed 's/\\N/NULL/g'
```

Of course, you cannot import that into MySQL until you want the string **NULL** to be the value to be imported.

Comment: I tried the --hex-blob flag but it didn't produce anything different than \n.  This may be due that fields in the affected table aren't any of the formats you specified.

Comment: Excellent, now I have Rolando's password ;)